# Trying to Validate XML to DTD- error saying ENTITY is not unparsed

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation

Im trying to validate an XML document against a DTD while using the Oxygen XML Editor tool
Towards the end of my code, an error message comes with 
E{XERCES} ENTITY "myent" is not unparsed.

Does anyone know what this error means, and if so how to fix it to make it runs so I can validate the XML?

The parameters are closed and an example of what it looks like is as so.

```
   <authentication board="myent"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show the full XML and DTD

Comment: Did my answer help? Is there anything that you did not understand?

Answer (score 3):

What the Xerces error is saying, basically, is that the ENTITY "myent" is not declared as an unparsed entity.

What is most likely the case (I'm guessing since you haven't supplied the DTD) is that the attribute `board` is declared as the type `ENTITY`. Attributes with the type `ENTITY` must match the name of a corresponding unparsed entity that is declared in the DTD.

Attribute type `ENTITY` validity constraint from the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attribute-types):

> Values of type ENTITY MUST match the Name production, values of type
>   ENTITIES MUST match Names; each Name MUST match the name of an
>   unparsed entity declared in the DTD.

Definition of unparsed entity from the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-unparsed):

> An unparsed entity is a resource whose contents may or
>   may not be text, and if text, may be other than XML. Each unparsed
>   entity has an associated notation, identified by name. Beyond a
>   requirement that an XML processor make the identifiers for the entity
>   and notation available to the application, XML places no constraints
>   on the contents of unparsed entities.

Here's an example of the `board` attribute being declared as the type `ENTITY` with no corresponding unparsed entity declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE authentication [
<!ELEMENT authentication EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST authentication
          board ENTITY #REQUIRED>
]>
<authentication board="myent"/>
```

The above example will generate the error (copied directly from oXygen using my first example below):

```
E [Xerces] ENTITY "myent" is not unparsed.
```

If we add the entity declaration (and the notation (NDATA) declaration; see [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-notation)), the XML is now valid:

```
<!DOCTYPE authentication [
<!ELEMENT authentication EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST authentication
          board ENTITY #REQUIRED>
<!NOTATION bar SYSTEM "bar">
<!ENTITY myent SYSTEM "FOO" NDATA bar>    
]>
<authentication board="myent"/>
```