# Validation error while declaring attribute type as entity in XML

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

Here is my DTD file.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XML Spy v3.0.7 NT (http://www.xmlspy.com) by Manukyan (YSU) -->
<!ENTITY xxx "ccc">
<!ENTITY yyy "ddd">
<!ELEMENT book (author+, title, publisher)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST title
    aaa ENTITY  #IMPLIED
>
```

And here is corresponding DSD file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\XML\XMLDB\XML\BOOK.DTD">
<book>
    <author>asd</author>
    <title aaa="xxx"/>
    <publisher/>
</book>
```

And I got a validation error saying that.
Value part 'xxx' of attribute 'aaa' must be the name of unparsed entity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411695/trying-to-validate-xml-to-dtd-error-saying-entity-is-not-unparsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Daniel Haley [explains in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415499/14419) to a similar question, if you add the entity declaration and the notation (NDATA) declaration for `ccc`, the XML is now valid:

```
<!DOCTYPE book [

<!NOTATION ccc SYSTEM "ccc">
<!ENTITY xxx SYSTEM "ccc" NDATA ccc>

<!ENTITY yyy "ddd">
<!ELEMENT book (author+, title, publisher)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST title aaa ENTITY  #IMPLIED>
]>
<book>
    <author>asd</author>
    <title aaa="xxx"/>
    <publisher/>
</book>
```